# Get specific XML Child node in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I am trying to load XMl to different tables with logical keys in MS SQL Server. 
I am stuck as I am getting all child nodes in SQL.

```
<Books>
<Book>
    <Name>Book1</Name>
    <Author>abc</Author>
    <Stores>
        <Name>Amazon</Name>
    </Stores>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Name>Book2</Name>
    <Author>cde</Author>
    <Stores>
        <Name>Flipkart</Name>
    </Stores>
</Book>
</Books>
```

I want to get result as below.

```
BookId  Name   Author  StoreXML
1       Book1  abc     <Stores><Name>Amazon</Name></Stores>  
2       Book2  cde     <Stores><Name>Flipkart</Name></Stores>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Books>
<Book>
    <Name>Book1</Name>
    <Author>abc</Author>
    <Stores>
        <Name>Amazon</Name>
    </Stores>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Name>Book2</Name>
    <Author>cde</Author>
    <Stores>
        <Name>Flipkart</Name>
    </Stores>
</Book>
</Books>';

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS BookId --there is no id in your XML...
      ,b.value('(Name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS BookName 
      ,b.value('(Author/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Author
      ,b.query('Stores') AS StoreXML 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Books/Book') AS A(b)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using @xml.query rather than b.query to get specific child node.